# Can't change my react icon while expanding my Accordion in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I can't change my react icon while expanding my Accordion in Bootstrap. The 'Click me' content is dropping down and showing correctly but the icon still stucks.

```
 function Expander () {

  const[active,setActive] = useState(false);


  return (
    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
  <Card>
    <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
      {active ? <GrAddCircle size='20px'/> : <AiOutlineMinusCircle size='20px'/>}
      Click me!
    </Accordion.Toggle>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0" onClick={()=>setActive(!active)}>
      <Card.Body>Hello! I'm the body</Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="1">
      Click me!
    </Accordion.Toggle>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
      <Card.Body>Hello! I'm another body</Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
  </Card>
</Accordion>
  );
}

export default Expander;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `setActive` method is never getting called only, which is resulting in active flag to never turn `true`.

Why are you adding `onClick` listener on the `Accordion.Collapse` element, it should be on the `Accordion.Toggle` element.